# setLocation should take two parameters, singlePerson and city. It should set a location property on the person to the city

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to set the location property to the variable person but it's giving me this error 1: "setLocation Function > When invoked will set a location property of a person to the value passed" 2: "Expected undefined to be defined." 3: "Expected undefined to be 'Boston'."

I have tried

```
person.location = 'city';
person.city = 'Boston';

function Person(firstName, lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    return;
};

var person = new Person('ciara', 'mosca');

function getAge(person){
    return person.age;
};

function getPerson(){
    var person = {firstName: 'paolo', lastName: 'mosca'};
    return person;
};

function setAge(person){
    person.age = 21;
};

function setLocation(singlePerson, city){
    person.location = "city";
};

function transportPerson(person){
    setLocation();{
    person.location = "LA";
    }
};
```

> Error: Expected undefined to be defined.
>   Error: Expected undefined to be 'Boston'.

Comment: This code is really convoluted. Most of those functions - except for `Person` - are never used anywhere, why are they even declared? The code that actually runs is `person.location = 'city';
person.city = 'Boston';
var person = new Person('ciara', 'mosca');` and I would expect that to throw an exception because of the wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};

var person = new Person('ciara', 'mosca');

console.log('new person', person);

function getAge(person){
    return person.age || 0;
};

console.log('getAge', getAge(person)); // 0 since not defined

function getPerson(){
    var person = {firstName: 'paolo', lastName: 'mosca'};
    return person;
};

console.log('getPerson', getPerson()); // paolo mosca object

function setAge(person){
    person.age = 21;
};

setAge(person);
console.log("person's age", getAge(person)); // now 21

function setLocation(singlePerson, city){
    singlePerson.location = city; // use both the parameters passed in!
};

setLocation(person, 'tokyo');
console.log(person); // person but with location property in tokyo now

function transportPerson(person){
    setLocation(person, 'IDK where they went!!'); // pass person to set location, also need to pass a second parameter.
};

transportPerson(person);
console.log(person); // now they got transported somewhere!
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the double quotes in `"city"`  also you have to use the passed parameter as is `singlePerson` not `person` to be like this

```
function setLocation(singlePerson, city){
            singlePerson.location = city;
        };

setLocation(person, "Boston")
```

Also you have another mistake in `transportPerson` function parameters has to be in parentheses and separated by commas like this.

```
        function transportPerson(person){
            setLocation(person , "LA" );
        };
```

Please check [how to use functions in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)